# Binning non-scalar objects in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, binning

I would like to chart the conditional probability of some event `A` happening with regards to some variable `X`. I have a dataset of samples where each sample is a pair of a value `X` and weather `A` happened for `X`.
I would like to chart this conditional probability by binning the data based on variable X, and setting the height of each column/bin to `p/(N-p)` where `N` is the number of samples in the bin, and `p` is the number of samples where `A` happened.

I found `pandas.cut` which can implement binning, however, it only accepts scalars and produces a histogram type output. Is there any function/library which can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do can be accomplished by a groupby operation. Most of this code is just to setup a df like the one you describe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Build up the df you describe
num_vs = 20
vs = ['x{0:03d}'.format(v) for v in range(num_vs)]
event_outcomes = [True,False]

max_trials_per_v = 100
trials_per_v = np.random.randint(1,max_trials_per_v,num_vs)

data = {
    'X':[],
    'A':[],
}
for v,t in zip(vs,trials_per_v):
    outcomes = np.random.choice(event_outcomes,t,replace=True)
    data['X'].extend([v]*t)
    data['A'].extend(outcomes)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


#Calculate p and N for each X
agg_df = df.groupby('X').agg(
    p = ('A','sum'),
    N = ('A','count'),
).reset_index()

#Calculate the fraction (not sure if this is supposed to be a probability, but its not)
agg_df['p/(N-p)'] = agg_df['p']/(agg_df['N']-agg_df['p'])

#Bar plot 
agg_df.plot.barh(x='X',y='p/(N-p)')
```

[image: barplot]